# TextView Text Exceeds from TextArea

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm doing work on chat module. I'm using TextView for send message but when text exceeds from textview height, textView not scrolling infect text showing out from TextView text area. 
   [image]

I'm using this code for expanding textview content area with respect to text.

```
private let kMessageViewWidths = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 168)

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    self.setTextViewSizeWithContent()
}
func setTextViewSizeWithContent() {

    let newSize = self.calculateSize(chatTextView: self.messageTF, chatText: self.messageTF.text, withFixedSize: kMessageViewWidths)
    self.messageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
func calculateSize(chatTextView: UITextView, chatText: String, withFixedSize: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = chatText
    textView.frame = chatTextView.frame
    textView.font = chatTextView.font
    textView.tag = chatTextView.tag
    let fixedWidth = withFixedSize
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: chatTextView.contentSize.height)
    newSize.height = newSize.height + CGFloat(30)

    if newSize.height > 100 {
        newSize.height = 100
    }
    return newSize
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the height constraint, try changing the frame of the textView.

You have to calculate for a new y position. Keep in mind when you change the height of a view, but keep a constant y position, the view gets taller in the downward direction.

```
func setTextViewSizeWithContent() {

    let newSize = self.calculateSize(chatTextView: self.messageTF, chatText: self.messageTF.text, withFixedSize: kMessageViewWidths)
    self.messageTF.frame = CGRect(x: yourXPosition, y: newYposition, 
    width: yourTextViewWidth, height: newsize.height)    
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```